# Does Kubernetes mount an emtpyDir volume on the host?

Tags: kubernetes

Kubernetes features quite a few types of volumes, [including `emptyDir`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#types-of-volumes):

> An `emptyDir` volume is first created when a Pod is assigned to a Node, and exists as long as that Pod is running on that node. As the name says, it is initially empty. Containers in the pod can all read and write the same files in the `emptyDir` volume, though that volume can be mounted at the same or different paths in each container. When a Pod is removed from a node for any reason, the data in the `emptyDir` is deleted forever.
>
> ...
>
> **By default, emptyDir volumes are stored on whatever medium is backing the node.**

Is the `emtpyDir` actually mounted on the node, and accessible to a container outside the pod, or to the node FS itself?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes it is also accessible on the node. It is bind mounted into the container (sort of). The source directories are under **`/var/lib/kubelet/pods/PODUID/volumes/kubernetes.io~empty-dir/VOLUMENAME`**

You can find the location on the host like this:

```
sudo ls -l /var/lib/kubelet/pods/`kubectl get pod -n mynamespace mypod -o 'jsonpath={.metadata.uid}'`/volumes/kubernetes.io~empty-dir
```

Comment: Are they meant to be directly accessible this way?

Comment: Yes, if you are inside node

Comment: just to add. Although they are available on node FS they are NOT accessible by containers outside the pod who created it.

Answer (score 0):

You can list all emptyDir volumes on the host using this command

`df`

To view only volumes mapped to a specific volume

`df | grep -i cache-volume`

where **cache-volume** is the volume name in your pod definition

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: k8s.gcr.io/test-webserver
    name: test-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /cache
      name: cache-volume
  volumes:
  - name: cache-volume
    emptyDir: {}
```