# How to find out where kubelet is creating the emptyDirs?

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

I know where the location is by default which is under `/var/lib/kubelet`

However I don't want to depend on this knowledge. I'd like to get the location using command line or checking some config file (which hopefully is stored in a more permanent location).

Is there a way to determine where the location is? if indeed changed by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it depends how the `root-dir` parameter was applied to the kubelet:

F.e you should see this in `systemctl status kubelet`.

Another approach is to search for KubeletRootDir `journalctl -u kubelet | grep KubeletRootDir`

So please use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46526490/11207414)  `-root-dir by default = /var/lib/kubelet/`

```
sudo ls -l /root-dir/`kubectl get pod -n mynamespace mypod -o 'jsonpath={.metadata.uid}'`/volumes/kubernetes.io~empty-dir/monted_volume
```

Hope this help.