# Kubernetes how different mountPath share data in single pod

Tags: kubernetes

I read an article [from here](https://www.stratoscale.com/blog/kubernetes/kubernetes-how-to-share-disk-storage-between-containers-in-a-pod/) which the data is shared in the same Pod with 2 different containers. These 2 containers both have `volumnMount` on name, **shared-data**. But both of them having different `mountPath`.

[image]

[image]

My question is, if these `mountPath` are not same, how are they sharing data? And what is the path for the volume **shared-data**? My thought is, both should have the same path in order to share data, and i seems like mistaken some concept, but not sure what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubernetes maintains the storage internally.  It doesn't have a fixed path that you can see, and it doesn't matter if it gets mounted in the same place in different containers.

By way of analogy, imagine you have an external USB drive.  If you've unplugged the drive, it doesn't make sense to ask "what is its path"; and if you plug it in and mount it on `/mnt/usb` on one machine, that doesn't stop you from mounting it on `/home/me/app/data` when you plug it into a different machine.

The volume does have a name within its pod (in your example, `shared-data`).  If the volume is backed by a PersistentVolumeClaim that will also have a name.  Potentially the matching PersistentVolume is something like an AWS EBS volume, and *that* will have a name.  But none of these names are fixed filesystem paths, and for the most part you can't directly use these to access the file content.

Answer (score 1):

There is  **only** one volume being created "shared-data" which in being declared in pod initially empty :
`volumes:- name: shared-data emptyDir: {}`
and shared between these two containers .That volume exists on the pod level and it existence only depends on the pod not the two containers .However its bind mounted by the two : meaning whatever you add/edit on the one container or the other , will affect the volume (in your case adding index.html from the debian container).. and yes you can find the path of the volume :`/var/lib/kubelet/pods/PODUID/volumes/kubernetes.io~empty-dir/VOLUMENAME` .. there is similar question answered  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46526490/6796118)